# How to submit URL parameter with the form as a hidden value

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, parameters

I have a URL `http://www.example.com/page?params=2`.
How can i submit this parameter value with the submission of a form as an hidden type?

Comment: Using a `hidden` input with `name="params"` and `value="2"`?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca what if a value can vary every time?

Comment: Where is your form?

Comment: on the current page which has this URL

Comment: Edit your question and add your form HTML?

Comment: Ok, but how does that value change? I mean, if it changes you change the `value` of that input. I don't understand what's your question.

Comment: you can get url params using super global variable $_GET inside your form

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca values may vary when bringing different values from different pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the `GET` method to read the value of the param then assign that value to the hidden input as a value attr

```
//http://www.example.com/page?params=2

$param = isset($_GET['params']) ? intval($_GET['params']) :null;

?>

<input type="hidden" name="params" value="<?php echo $param;?>">
```

Comment: how do i check if the parameter value is passed correctly after using this through the inspect console?

Comment: the devtool is posting the value as <?=$param?>  @masivuye

Comment: The form is sending this string `<?php echo $param;?>` as value not the actual value. 

`------WebKitFormBoundaryS4qIfsTExsy5LFmh
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="page"

<?php echo $param;?>`

Answer (score 0):

you can define hidden input control inside your form.

```
<input type='hidden' name='params' value='<?= htmlentities ( $_GET["params"], ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML401 | ENT_SUBSTITUTE | ENT_DISALLOWED, 'UTF-8', true ); ?>'>
```

Then you can get hidden params after you submit form.

Comment: and enjoy having your user accounts getting hacked. this code is wide open to XSS javascript injection. fixing it and you get  `<input type='hidden' name='params' value='<?= htmlentities ( $_GET["params"], ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML401 | ENT_SUBSTITUTE | ENT_DISALLOWED, 'UTF-8', true );  ?>'>`

Comment: btw, exploiting it would look like `http://example.org/page.php?params=%3E%3Cscript%3Ealert%28%22vulnerable%21%22%29%3B%3C%2Fscript%3E`

Comment: PHP will automatically url-decode it for you before putting it in $_GET

Answer (score 0):

Write a input text field in the form such as::

```
<input type="hidden" name="customName" value="customValue">
```

Now while submitting the form, the parameter name will be `customName` and its value will be `customValue`.